# Create a new DOM element with EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am rendering a view with the EJS template engine based on some dynamic variables. For example:

```
    res.render("index", {
        dynamicVariable: newEverytime
    });
```

I am currently inserting it inside my HTML like so

```
    <% if(someCondition){ %>
       <div>
           <a href="#"><%= dynamicVariable %></a>  
       </div>
    <% } %>
```

I want EJS to create a new `<a>`tag every time as opposed to replacing my a tag each time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

EJS on the server side doesn't create any DOM nodes. It processes HTML source code as text. It just prints strings and it's the HTML parser on the client side that creates the DOM nodes from that.

I think you are asking about a strange solution to a problems that you say nothing about. It would b more useful to ask about the actual problems you're having, what have you tried so far and why it's not working.

Comment: I am saving some links to the home screen, the text inside the links, as well as the href attribute is different every time. How can I render these to my HTML without each new link replacing the existing one?